# How to Make a button that directly Extends Actor? Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to make a button that directly extends Actor. The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to go through the trouble of making a text button that has skins and such. I just want to be able to load my png file on the screen and make it clickable. Anyone have ideas or should I just stick to the Textbutton?

Comment: You can do that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about an ImageTextButton?

Or you use a Button, and add a Stack (which holds multiple items, that you can place on them self)

I don't recommend you, to do your own button. You'll reinvent the wheel.

I suggest: try ImageTextButton.
If that does not help --> Button + Stack

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextureActor extends Actor {

    private Texture texture;

    public TextureActor(Texture texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

You can certainly replace `Texture` with anything else which can be drawn by the batch. Or use another `draw` method with more detailed parameters.

Comment: So I did something like this, but I was stuck on getting it to handle click events. I tried using the ClickedListener, but it didn't seem to work. I am not sure if it was because I did something wrong or I simply can't add a ClickListener to an Actor object (Which doesn't really make sense to me).

Comment: Maybe you forgot to setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

Answer (score 0):

Buttons don't actually need a skin, so it would be far easier to just make a factory method to simplify it, rather than code all the logic of a proper button:

```
public static Button makeButton (TextureRegion upImage, TextureRegion downImage, Actor contentActor) {
    Button.ButtonStyle style = new Button.ButtonStyle();
    style.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(upImage);
    style.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(downImage);
    return contentActor == null ? new Button(style) : new Button(contentActor, style);
}
```